# PostgreSQL error: CASE with JSON set-returning functions

Tags: postgresql, case, postgresql-10, lateral-join

I've got a SELECT statement with a CASE that uses JSON functions, which stopped working when upgrading to PostgreSQL 10.

```
SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN type = 'a' THEN data #>> '{key_a,0}'
            WHEN type = 'b' THEN data #>> '{key_a,0,key_b,0}'
            WHEN type = 'c' THEN jsonb_object_keys(data #> '{key_c,key_d}')
            ELSE NULL
        END AS foo,
        CASE
            WHEN type = 'a' THEN jsonb_array_elements_text(data -> 'key_e')
            WHEN type = 'b' THEN data #>> '{key_f,0,key_g}'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS bar
```

> ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
>
> Hint: You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.

I don't understand how using a LATERAL FROM is an alternative. In fact, I don't fully understand why LATERAL would be used, even when reading [the PG docs (section 7.2.1.5)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html).

Any ideas how this statement would be converted to work with PG 10?

Comment: As long as neither of those functions will ever return more than 1 row (which only you will know based on your data), you can just put them in a sub-select: `THEN (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(data #> '{key_c,key_d}'))`

Comment: @eurotrash that works in my situation, thanks! If you move your comment to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as none of those set-returning functions will return more than one row, you can put them in a subquery to get around the restriction:

```
SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN type = 'a' THEN data #>> '{key_a,0}'
            WHEN type = 'b' THEN data #>> '{key_a,0,key_b,0}'
            WHEN type = 'c' THEN (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(data #> '{key_c,key_d}'))
            ELSE NULL
        END AS foo,
        CASE
            WHEN type = 'a' THEN (SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(data -> 'key_e'))
            WHEN type = 'b' THEN data #>> '{key_f,0,key_g}'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS bar
```