# What is the complete list of "set-returning functions" in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Working on upgrading a PostgreSQL 9.6 database to 10+, I am encountering the breaking change that set-returning functions, such as `jsonb_object_keys` and `json_array_elements_text`, can no longer be used in `CASE` expressions.

Where can the definitive list of set-returning functions (including built-ins) be found in PostgreSQL - it doesn't appear that there is a reference in the PostgreSQL documentation, and the result set of `SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines` does not appear to have an obvious column that indicates 'result type is a set'.

Comment: Unrelated, but: I hope you are not upgrading to 10 as that is EOL in about 3 months as well

Comment: Yep, definitely upgrading to 14!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the system catalog `pg_proc`.

```sql
select *
from pg_proc
where proretset
```

According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html) the column `proretset` contains this information.

> proretset bool
>
> Function returns a set (i.e., multiple values of the specified data type)

See also [PostgreSQL error: CASE with JSON set-returning functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52384245/1995738)